# Difference days between datetime and date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get the number of days from today until End_Date field. On of them is in datetime and other in date format.

```
SELECT    [Alternate_number] ,[DP1], [Delivery_date],  
  [Deliver_to_EDI_warehouse_number], 
  CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT([Delivery_date], 10), 110) AS End_DATE, 
  convert(date, getdate()) as Today,
  'POTS' as Cube

FROM  [dbo].[Cube_Splits_POTS]
WHERE (CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT([Delivery_date], 10), 110) > GETDATE()) AND
      (CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT([Delivery_date], 10), 110) < GETDATE() + 14)
```

Comment: This is SQL apologies

Comment: Which SQL Server / System are you using? Date/Time formats are handled very differently among different SQL systems.

Comment: Which SQL? I suspect SQL Server but it needs to be stated

Comment: SQL server 2012 pls

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your datetime to date like this:

```
CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

To get the days difference between two dates you can use:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, DateOne, dateTwo)
```